# Vlookup over a range, returning incorrect Value Or #N/A

Tags: excel-formula

Perhaps it's just been a long day (a **really** long day apparently), but I can't figure why my formula is returning the wrong thing...

I have a table (note: Top left is `B1`, bottom right is `D6`).

```
Min Score   Max       Score 
101.00      1000.00     A+
81.00       100.00      A
51.00       80.00       B+
41.00       50.00       B
-4000.00    40.00       C
```

(Or here's a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzwzs.jpg) if someone prefers)

my vlookup formula is: `=Vlookup(C8,B2:D6,3,TRUE)`

I expect to return "A" when the lookup is `100`, "B" if I'm looking up a number from 41 to 50, etc.  ( My cells are formatted to Numbers.)

Currently, for a lookup value of `100`, it's returning "C". What am I overlooking?  If I change `100` to `50`, it returns an `#N/A` error!

Edit: I've sorted with the "Min Score" as ascending and it worked!

Comment: Sort column B ascending

Comment: @Scott - ooh thanks, I'll try tomorrow when I'm back in Excel.

Comment: when using vlookup and looking for closest mat instead of exact match (true vs false for last argument) the look up range must be sorted in ascending order as per Scott's earlier comment.  If you  want to keep your numbers in descending order then you would need to use an INDEX/MATCH combination with the 3rd argument for match set to -1.

Comment: @ScottCraner - That did it, thanks!

Comment: @ForwardEd - Thanks for that explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree Column B needs to be sorted ascending.

The formula is also using relative reference's as opposed to absolute for its lookup which could make the formula not work if it is auto-filled down.

`=VLOOKUP(C8,$B$2:D6,3,TRUE)`

Or nested if statements in place of Vlookup. 
     `=IF(C8<41,"C",IF(C8<51,"B",IF(C8<81,"B+",IF(C8<101,"A",IF(C8>=101,"A+","N/A")))))`

Comment: Thanks for this - while it certainly would work, I'm curious why the simple `vlookup()` isn't working. Also the formula with `if()` gets convoluted pretty quickly when I want to add even more grades. Thanks though!

Comment: Column B does need to be sorted ascending. I think I may have found the problem, the formula is using relative reference's as opposed to absolute for its lookup table.                                                         =VLOOKUP(C8,$B$2:D6,3,TRUE)

Comment: But the relative vs absolute reference shouldn't matter unless I plan on dragging/moving the formula, no?

Comment: The solution was that I needed to sort by Ascending, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH(B8,B2:B6,-1)),"OFF the chart")
```

Use the above in C8 and you will not need to change your chart order.

On a side note, a score of 80.5 will be an A as the breakpoint is 80.  Your minimum column has nothing to do with the calc but is aesthetically pleasing to my eye to see the range in 1 row.

[image: pROOF OF CONCEPT]

Comment: For the differences between [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)'s *[range_lookup]* parameter and [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca)'s *[match_type]* parameter consult the documentation.

Comment: Ohhh I see now, you just used a single column in the `Match()` part.  Thanks for this.  Since my question was about `Vlookup()`, I've marked the other as answer, but this is a great help and tool to add to my index/match knowledge!